# Fusion tables objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a problem with coordinates from Fusion Tables, I need to pass these points to objective-c, something readable like a simple point (latitude, longitude):

Example:

```
<Point>coordinates>-9.153105,38.733661,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point>coordinates>-9.1501588,38.7366884,0.0</coordinates></Point>
```

Is there a way to do it?

**Edit:** Sorry for being vague, I'm trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude from these strings,

What I tried so far, but with no success:

```
NSString *latitude = [aux substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (19, 8)];
NSString *longitude = [aux substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (30, 8)];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  What's the exact nature of your problem?  What have you tried?  What are the actual results of what you've tried and how do they compare to the actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for three floats which you know are separated by a comma. I would use NSScanner to pick up the three numbers. It's very good at that sort of thing.

Comment: There is an example in this section of my book that will get you started: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsstring_and_friends